# Why does bash have two distinct sets of options?

Tags: bash

Bash seems to divide its set of options in two types. I am interested in understanding the reason for this.

To clarify, if I run the `shopt` command, I get a list of options and their statuses (on/off), but if I run `shopt -o`, I get a different list of options. Even the documentation of `shopt` (`help shopt`) seems to make that distinction:

```
  -o    restrict OPTNAMEs to those defined for use with `set -o'
```

In other words, there are options that can be set with `set -o`, but options which can only be set with the `shopt` command. Why does bash contain two different sets of options? Why not simply have all options set with the `shopt` command?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because bash is a "kitchen sink" shell.  The `set -o` options are used in all Bourne based shells.  `set -o vi` does the same thing in ksh, that it does in bash, e.g.

After that, someone thought bash needed more options that weren't bourne compatible, so shopt was born.  Some are good, some are odd.

Also, if that seems odd-- you should see the default handling of `for` loops in bash and other POSIX shells!

```
for i in *.txt; do
   mv $i /tmp/
   echo hi
done
mv: cannot stat ‘*.txt’: No such file or directory
hi
```

Tangential, the default behavior when there is NO match is to get the file glob as a string literal, making the above try to execute the loop once with `mv \*.txt  /tmp/` instead of skipping the loop.  How is that related to shopt?

`shopt -s nullglob` can be set before the loop to have the glob expand to nothing, which `for` will skip.  However, you then need to `shopt -u nullglob`, b/c commands like ls will execute with no arguments, which may not work as intended.

Summary-- bash has accepted every "good" idea someone wanted to throw at it.  Figuratively, anyway.

Comment: (Re: globs expanding to themselves with no matches) -- "in bash"? That's POSIX-specified behavior. Bash *has* to implement it to fulfil the spec. And standard UNIX tools depend on it: Without that behavior, `ls *.txt` would list everything in your directory if no matches exist, instead of being able to give you an error, like `ls: *.txt: not found`.

Comment: (and I strenuously dispute that `nullglob` is an example of a poorly-thought-through feature, when you demonstrate its value -- in being able to disable potentially-undesirable standard-mandated behavior -- just a few paragraphs above).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If there are no matches in SysV's ksh in a for loop, the loop is skipped.  This is also the behavior of a null value variable in every program language.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the need of nullglob is what's odd-- instead of `*.txt` evaluating to an empty set, it evaluates to a string literal-- I'll need to see a link to how that's a POSIX requirement, b/c I've seen it no where else.

Comment: Quoting from section 2.13.3 of [the POSIX sh spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html): "If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale. If the pattern contains an invalid bracket expression or does not match any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern string shall be left unchanged."

Comment: And `ksh -c 'for f in *.nonexisting; do echo "$f"; done'` emits `*.nonexisting` on output with the 2012-08-01 release of ksh93u+; same for dash 0.5.9.1, mksh R55, and pdksh 5.2.14. I don't have a single shell that claims to be a POSIX superset on hand that *doesn't* have that behavior (zsh being a notable exception, inasmuch as its its behavior equivalent to bash with bash with `shopt -s failglob`, but it makes no such claim except when started under the name `sh` -- in which case it too emits `*.nonexistent` on output).

Comment: `(exec -a sh zsh -c 'for f in *.nonexisting; do echo "$f"; done')`, if you want to test that last, btw.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no rant, the only rant is coming from you and you are off based and have picked up a banner to wave around.  I didn't recall ksh every giving me that issue, which was whichever ksh was on Solaris2.6, 7, and 8 when I worked on it.  I've only experienced this unwanted behavior since moving to a Linux company.  I'll remove the ksh reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148076/discussion-between-sainthax-and-charles-duffy).